# sass математические операции

Tags: sass, препроцессор

Правильно ли показала моя практика 2 день как интересуюсь препроцессором, будет ли валидные следующие строки :12px/2 или 12/2px(не компилируется)?
или математические операции работают только с переменными типа:$som/2 или $som*3 ?

Comment: А вы пробовали их, собстна, скомпилировать?

Comment: ну да , 12px/2 не работает а с переменными работает и хотел услышать ответ профессионала

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Из [документации по Sass](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#division-and-slash) (перевожу):

> ### Деление и `/`
>
> В CSS знак `/` употребляется как разделитель для чисел. Поскольку SassScript расширяет стандартный CSS-синтаксис свойств, он должен поддерживать такое поведение, но при этом позволяя использовать `/` и для деления. То есть, по умолчанию, два числа, разделённые `/`, попадут в таком же виде в результат.
>
> Но есть три ситуации, в которых `/` будет обработан, как оператор деления:
>
> 1. Если значение, или любая его часть, **переменная** или **результат вызова функции**
> 2. Если значение в скобках
>
>    - Кроме случаев, когда скобки вокруг списка, а значение в списке
> 3. Если значение является частью другого арифметического выражения
>
> #### Примеры:
>
> ```
> p {
>   font: 10px/8px;               // Обычный CSS, нет деления
>   $width: 1000px;
>   width: $width/2;              // В выражении переменная, будет деление
>   width: round(1.5)/2;          // В выражении вызов функции, будет деление
>   height: (500px/2);            // Значение в скобках, будет деление
>   margin-left: 5px + 8px/2px;   // В выражении +, будет деление
>   font: (italic bold 10px/8px); // В скобках целый список, они не повлияют: нет деления
> }
> ```
>
> #### Результат:
>
> ```
> p {
>   font: 10px/8px;
>   width: 500px;
>   height: 250px;
>   margin-left: 9px; }
> ```